# Show $A = \{ u \in S^+(E) \textrm{ | } \forall x \in K, \langle x, u(x) \rangle \leq 1 \}$ is a compact set

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hilbert-spaces, compactness, self-adjoint-operators

**The problem**

Let $\left( E, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle \right)$ be a euclidean space of dimension $n$. Let $K$ be a compact subset of $E$ containing a basis $e = (e_1, ..., e_n)$ of $E$.

We denote by $S^+(E)$ the set of self-adjoint endomorphisms of $E$ with non-negative eigenvalues.

Let I want to show that $A := \{ u \in S^+(E) \textrm{ | } \forall x \in K, \langle x, u(x) \rangle \leq 1 \}$ is a compact subset of $\mathcal{L}(E)$.

I have already proved $A$ is a closed subset of $\mathcal{L}(E)$, using sequential characterisation and without using the compactness of $K$. So, what remains to prove is the boundedness of $A$.

**What I have tried**

Let $u \in A$. The spectral theorem gives us an orthonormal basis $f = (f_1, ..., f_n)$ composed of eigenvectors of $u$, with eigenvalues $\lambda_1, ..., \lambda_n$.

We decompose each $e_i = a_{1i}f_1 + ... + a_{ni}f_n$ (so that $M := (a_{ij}) = \textrm{Mat}_{f}(e)$). As $f$ is orthonormal and $e_i \in K$, one has $\langle e_i, u(e_i) \rangle = a_{1i}^2\lambda_1 + ... + a_{ni}^2\lambda_n \leq 1$. Denoting $\Lambda := (\lambda_1, ..., \lambda_n)^T$ and $N := (a_{ij}^2)$ we can claim that $N \Lambda$ is bounded.

My goal now is to show that $\Lambda$ is bounded by something which does not depend on $u$. Indeed, the spectral radius is a norm on $S(E)$.

But there is one main several obstacle: I do not manage to get rid of $N$, which depends on $u$, because the $a_{ij}$ do. Furthermore, I suspect the compactness of $K$ is useful here, but I cannot figure out any link with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a little funny the way the problem is written. Here is what you need to show. Consider the matrices $$M_n^+(\mathbf{R}) = \{P \in \mathbf{R}^{n \times n} : P = P^T, P \succeq 0\}$$ 
These are canonically identified with the set $S^+(E)$ of self-adjoint, endomorphisms you give before (viz. the spectral theorem).

Consequently, you only need to show that 
$$
A = \left\{U \in M_n^+(\mathbf{R}) : \sup_{x \in K} x^T U x \leq 1\right\}$$ 
is a compact set. Closure is simple: if $U_n \to U$, $U_n \in A$, then 
$x^TU_n x \leq 1$ for all $x \in K$. Moreover the sequence $\{x^TU_n x\}$ is bounded since $x$ are bounded and $U_n$ converges. Consequently, we see that $x^T U x \leq 1$, and therefore $A$ is closed.

For bounded, it is quite easy. The operator norm is always achieved in finite dimensions. So let $x$ be a unit vector, achieving the operator norm for $U^{1/2}$, with $U \in A$. Then we may write $x = \sum_i c_i e_i$, where $e_i$ denote the basis contained in $K$. Then 
$$\|U^{1/2}\| = \|U^{1/2} x\| \leq \sum_i |c_i| \|U^{1/2} e_i\| = \sum_{i=1}^n |c_i| \leq B.
$$
The existence of $B$ follows by compactness.
Moreover, $\|U\| \leq \|U^{1/2}\|^2 \leq B^2$. So $A$ is bounded.

Comment: $(e_i)$ is not assumed to be orthonormal.

Comment: I don't see the $\sum |c_i| \le \sqrt{n}$. However, there is a constant $C$ such that $\sum |c_i|\le C$ because all the norms are equivalent.

Comment: You're right that orthonormality would be required for my previous solution to get the explicit constant $\sqrt{n}$. Here's a quite explicit way to see the existence of the constant now called $B$. Let $E$ denote the matrix corresponding to the basis, which we may write $E = QR$, by Gram-Schmidt, $R$ being an invertible matrix, $Q$ being orthogonal. Then $1 = \|x\| = \|Ec\| = \|Rc\| \geq r \|c\|$, where we have now taken $r = \inf_{\|c\| = 1} \|Rc\| > 0$ by full-rank. Now we have $\sum_i |c_i| \leq \sqrt{n}\|c\| \leq  \frac{\sqrt{n}}{r}$. Take $B = \sqrt{n}/r$.

Comment: @DrewBrady You don't need an explicit B. You know that $x\mapsto \sum |c_i|$ is a norm, hence $B$ exists.

Comment: Sure--I thought I'd include it since there was some contention about its existence. I agree that it is a norm. (In fact, the quantitative version I put above is related to your comment identifying $c = E^{-1} x$, and $\|E^{-1}x\|_1$ is a norm.)

Comment: Could you clarify your argument about $B$ exists because of compactness? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MrMaths, that is what my comment about $B$ says above, explicitly, you can even take $B = \sqrt{n}/r$, with $r = \inf_{\|c\| = 1} \|Rc\|$, where $E = QR$, and $Q$ being an orthogonalization of the given basis, $R$ be the coefficients from Gram-Schmidt and $E$ the given basis written as a matrix. As pointed out from the discussion above, in fact the map $x \mapsto \sum_i |c_i|$ is a norm, and consequently since $x$ has unit norm by equivalence of the norms in finite dimensions, such a constant necessarily exists.